# How to read the full data bytes of positive diagnostic service via trace interface by using Vector CANoe

Tags: capl, canoe

I have difficulty reading full length of data bytes via trace interface when the data bytes I need are over the upper limit which traceface can show.

I want to using service 22 to read a trail of VIN ,ecuSoftApplicationNumber or anything else by sending Diagnostic message via CAN IG:

My first step is to add message 0x760 to CAN IG and change its raw data to 03 22 C2 44 00 00 00 00, then I send this message to the CAN BUS.Next I open the trace interface to see the response message 0x768 I received,the trace interface shows 10 0B 62 C2 44 FB 03 FF，as the rule shows ,the first 10 means the message consists of 10 bytes,However,I could only saw 8 bytes actually via the trace interface.so I want to know how to do to see the rest data bytes via trace interface.(circled in the picture )

The hint I get is to send another frame to let the whole data bytes show via trace interface.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzP9v.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The data is exchanged using the [ISO 1576-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_15765-2) protocol.

The data you have received from the ECU is `10 0B 62 C2 44 FB 03 FF`

This is to be interpreted as follows:

`1`: This is a first frame, i.e. the data to be sent by the ECU is larger than 7 bytes, thus it is split over one first frame and several consecutive frames.

`0 0B`: This is the length of the actual payload. Here `0x00B`, i.e. 11 bytes

The remaining 6 bytes `62 C2 44 FB 03 FF` are the first 6 bytes of the payload.

After this first frame - according to the protocol - the ECU waits for a *flow control frame* from the tester before sending the rest of the data.
The purpose of the flow control frame is to tell the ECU how fast it should send the remaining data.

The easiest way for you would be to send `30 00 08`.

This means:

`3`: This is a flow control frame

`0`: Continue to send the remaining data

`00`: Send all data (without waiting for further flow control frames)

`08`: Separate the remaining frames by 8 milliseconds (can be anything between 0 and 127)

Comment: Thanks for your guidance.I will have a try:)